# Read some csv files and combine them into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to write a code snippet as shown below. Main goal is to read from 03-10-2020.csv to from 03-16-2020.csv and merge them into one dataframe but only last dataframe is included in the dataframe.
How can I fix it?

```
week_array = []
path = 'URL_ADDRESS'


for i in range(10,17):
    dataset_date = "03-" + str(i) + "-2020.csv"
    url = path + dataset_date
    data_df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "utf-8" , index_col=None, header=0)
    week_array.append(data_df)
    week_df = pd.concat(week_array, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: move `pd.concat` outside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform deep copy for data_df.
data_df get replaced with data from new file each time.
hope this solves the issue.

```
week_array = []
path = 'URL_ADDRESS'


for i in range(10,17):
    dataset_date = "03-" + str(i) + "-2020.csv"
    url = path + dataset_date
    data_df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "utf-8" , header=0)
    week_array.append(data_df.copy()) ## deep copy

#concat outside loop by change indentation (same indentation like `week_array`)
week_df = pd.concat(week_array,axis=0, ignore_index=True)
#^^^^
print(week_df)
```

Comment: Hi, just updated the range, since I tested this with 3 files,kindly check again once. thank you.

Comment: @MichaelDunn - So if removed `.copy()` it not working, need `.copy()` ?

Comment: @jezrael i thought it was due to shallow copy the dataframe contains only latest element, so suggested deep copy.

Comment: @selvabalasubramanian - No, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717730/read-some-csv-files-and-combine-them-into-one-dataframe#comment107426859_60717778)

Comment: ic, @jezrael  tested on my local without .copy it works. but not sure why MichaelDunn is getting error.

Comment: @selvabalasubramanian - I think problem is something else, not this

Answer (score 0):

Use solution mentioned in comment, also is possible omit some default parameters like `index_col=None` and `axis=0` in `concat`:

```
week_array = []
path = 'URL_ADDRESS'


for i in range(10,17):
    dataset_date = "03-" + str(i) + "-2020.csv"
    url = path + dataset_date
    data_df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "utf-8" , header=0)
    week_array.append(data_df)

#concat outside loop by change indentation (same indentation like `week_array`)
week_df = pd.concat(week_array, ignore_index=True)
#^^^^
#here
```

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi I tried your code but it doesn't solve my issue. It always show the last one

Comment: @MichaelDunn - Is moved last row like in answer?

Comment: @jezrael I mean I shows only the data of last csv file

Comment: @MichaelDunn - So is changed your solution like my answer? Because in your solution it is expected, I think in my not.

Comment: @jezrael changed my code as yours but nothing changed. It still shows the values of the last csv file.

Comment: @MichaelDunn - What is `print (len(week_array))` before `concat` ?

Comment: @jezrael week_array is consisted of all csv files but week_df shows the values of the last csv file

Comment: @MichaelDunn - It is really weird, are data confidental?